# Basic Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to add even numbers to an array and then echo it out, here's my code but it just shows array() when I print...what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $x =88;
    $numbers = array();
    while ($x % 2 == 0 && $x <= 99) {
        $numbers[] = "$x";
        $x++;
    }
    print_r($numbers);
?>
```

Comment: `$numbers = range(88, 99, 2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move the "evenness" test from the `while` loop, and move it to a conditional within the `while` loop:

```
<?php
    $x = 88;
    $numbers = array();
    while ($x <= 99) {
        if ($x % 2 == 0) {
            $numbers[] = $x;
        }
        $x++;
    }
    print_r($numbers);
?>
```

As you have currently written the `while` loop, it ends if the number is not even. You should also remove the quotes from `$x` when you add to the `$numbers` array.